# in Azure Devops, how to apply automated build to existing pull request

Tags: azure-devops

I have an existing pull request that I would prefer not to have to abandon and restart.  There was no automated build set in the branch policy when the PR was created.  However, I have since linked an automated build.  Is there a way to make this change to the branch policies take effect without abandoning and recreating the PR?  I've already shared and posted the link for the PR, so I was hoping I could seamlessly make this change apply.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears if you just abandon your pull request then reactivate it right away, that makes all new branch policy changes apply.